# Совместимость с Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, java, aide

Я некоторое время пишу приложение на Android, и вчера попытался запустить его на Nexus 5 Android 5.0. При запуске выдаёт ошибку. На Android 4.4 работало исправно.
Приложение представляет из себя два потока, один из которых ежесекундно обновляет 2 собственных View-объекта, а второй — выполняет некоторый бесконечный цикл. 
Что могло послужить причиной того, что приложение не запускается на Android 5.0 Lollipop? Какие существуют методы обеспечения совместимости с Android 5.0 Lollipop?

Вот логи:

```
    11-17 10:34:08.335 7155 7155 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 10:34:08.335 7155 7155 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 10:34:08.335 7155 7155 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 10:34:08.335 7155 7155 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 10:34:08.335 7155 7155 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 10:34:08.335 7155 7155 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 12859
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 10:48:23.084 12859 12859 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 13437
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 10:49:28.244 13437 13437 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 14092
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 10 more
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float ru.dk.MGP.Level.getScale()' on a null object reference
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.OnB1Click(MainActivity.java:90)
11-17 10:51:36.126 14092 14092 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 13 more
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 14973
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 10:53:56.492 14973 14973 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 10:57:33.728 16887 16916 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2690
11-17 10:57:33.728 16887 16916 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 16887
11-17 10:57:33.728 16887 16916 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
11-17 10:57:33.728 16887 16916 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Particle.Move(Particle.java:411)
11-17 10:57:33.728 16887 16916 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MoveThread.run(MoveThread.java:17)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 17386
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 10:59:52.053 17386 17386 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 11:21:11.441 27841 27841 I   art                                          Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-17 11:21:11.579 27841 27841 W   art                                          Before Android 4.1, method ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder
11-17 11:21:11.583 27841 27841 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 27841
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 11:21:11.586 27841 27841 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 11:21:13.117 27841 27841 I   Process                                      Sending signal. PID: 27841 SIG: 9
11-17 11:21:39.712 28337 28337 I   art                                          Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-17 11:21:39.848 28337 28337 W   art                                          Before Android 4.1, method ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder
11-17 11:21:39.848 28337 28337 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 28337
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 11:21:39.849 28337 28337 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 11:21:41.732 28337 28337 I   Process                                      Sending signal. PID: 28337 SIG: 9
11-17 11:21:52.301 28622 28622 I   art                                          Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-17 11:21:52.415 28622 28622 W   art                                          Before Android 4.1, method ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder
11-17 11:21:52.415 28622 28622 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 28622
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 11:21:52.416 28622 28622 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 11:21:54.276 28622 28622 I   Process                                      Sending signal. PID: 28622 SIG: 9
11-17 11:32:12.936 31615 31615 I   art                                          Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-17 11:32:13.061 31615 31615 W   art                                          Before Android 4.1, method ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder
11-17 11:32:13.061 31615 31615 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.dk.MGP, PID: 31615
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int)"
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder.<init>(Level.java:217)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.<init>(Test_Level.java:58)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at ru.dk.MGP.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 11:32:13.066 31615 31615 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Без логов вам никто ничего сказать не сможет. Экстрасенсов тут нет)

Comment: Вот вам догадка из астрала: у вас targetSDK в манифесте ниже 21 поставлено.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ, к сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ, добавил логи.

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Немного порывшись в документации, я нашёл такую вещь, что абстрактные методы могут быть **ТОЛЬКО** public.

Comment: Абстрактные методы интерфейсов или абстрактных классов?

Comment: @argamidon, абстрактные методы классов. По крайней мере, в моём случае так было.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать другую версию библиотеки JSoup.
У меня была проблема с совместимостью JSoup 1.11.2 с Андроид 5.0 и 5.1.
Переход на версию JSoup 1.8.3 решил проблему.

Вот ссылка на мой вопрос (уже решено): [Jsoup не работает на андроид 5.0 (Lollipop)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781895/jsoup-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-5-0-lollipop/782681#782681)

Answer (score 0):

Единственно, что я понял (кстати, логов слишком много и они, кажись, повторяются), это то, что ругается на

> "Before Android 4.1, method ru.dk.MGP.Level ru.dk.MGP.Levels.Test_Level$Builder.getLevel(android.app.Activity, int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in ru.dk.MGP.Level$Builder"

Может, у вас какая библиотека подключена, коя и конфликтует с 5-й версией Андроида?

**Обновление**

Я не знаю, я просто делаю предположение на основе одной строчки из логов. =)
Поэкспериментируйте)

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ, какие библиотеки могут конфликтовать с 5.0?