# Jsoup не работает на андроид 5.0 (Lollipop)

Tags: jsoup

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с проблемой разного поведения Андроид с библиотекой Jsoup. Тестирую на 4.1 и 6.0 - всё работает исправно, тестирую на 5.1 - не работает.

К сути ситуации:
Есть веб-ресурс, который генерирует php-страницу с данными, по сути таблицу.
Код парсинга такой (убрал лишнее):

```
    class NewThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // класс который захватывает страницу
        Document doc;
        int docindex=0;
        String site ="http://simplename.ru/simple.php";
          //для примера, в реальности сайт другой
        do {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(site).get();
                // на этом моменте код стопится
                docindex = doc.childNodeSize();

                title = doc.select("td");
                titleList.clear();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (docindex == 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    }
}
```

На андроид 4 и 6 докупент захватывается полностью, и после полностью обрабатывается.
На андроид 5 не происходит захвата документа.
Если написать так:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(sitelink).maxBodySize(6000).get();
```

То происходит захват только части страницы сайта (таблицы), и соответственно только часть данных пападает под дальнейшую обработку.
Число 6000 подобрано методом тыка, если вводить больше 6330 - вероятно документ становиться слишком большим для Jsoup и срабатывает ограничение.
Я читал что у Jsoup есть какое-то ограничение на память, но как его изменить нигде не нашел.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы код одинаково работал на всех устройствах?
Как обойти ограничение Jsoup? Что мы указываем в maxBodySize? Байты?
Спасибо!

P.S. нашел на просторах ангоязычного интернета что для обхода ограничения в 1МБ на память надо писать так:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(sitelink).maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Это замечательно, но у меня так и было написано изначально. Проблема на Андроид 5.1 остается даже при таком варианте.

Comment: UPD. Взял за основу html таблицу вместо php-скрипта - итог тот же: если html документ имеет размер 6000 Байт и более, то Jsoup не захватывает документ. Если html документ имеет меньший размер - никаких проблем. 6 КБ совсем не похоже на ограничение Jsoup в 1 МБ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил проблему.
В начале проекта я выбрал самую последнюю версию Jsoup 1.11.2. И это, видимо, было ошибкой.
Сейчас я скачал и установил версию Jsoup 1.8.3 и всё работает одинаково на всех тестируемых аппаратах (в т.ч. и на Андроид 5.1), т.е. нет никаких проблем с захватом и обработкой большого html-документа.

Оставлю в своём проекте эту версию Jsoup.
Возможно позже я дополню свой ответ.